# Is it possible to use Izanagi on others?

Tags: naruto

In the anime(*Episode 338*, not sure though), I feel as if I saw an Uchiha member use *Izanagi* to revive a bunch of other Uchiha members. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, **YES**, Izanagi can be used on others. In Chapter 510, while explaining the history of Izanagi to Konan, Tobi himself states that the Sage of Six Paths used it to create things, such as the nine Bijuu.

*However*, is it possible for a random filler flashback Uchiha to use Izanagi on others? Probably not, because he did not have the Senju bloodline and is certainly not comparable to the Sage of Six Paths.

> Izanagi was originally a jutsu used by the Sage of Six Paths to "create". The Sage, who was the Uchiha and the Senju bloodlines in one person, used it to create many things.
>
> He would create shape and form from nothingness, using imagination and spiritual energy which forms basis of the Yin power, and then breathe life into that form using vitality and physical energy, which forms basis of the Yang power.
>
> **He also created the nine Bijuu from the Juubi's chakra.** A technique with the power to turn imagination into reality is the Izanagi.

[image: Izanagi explanation - 1]
[image: Izanagi explanation - 2]
[image: Izanagi explanation - 3]
[image: Izanagi explanation - 4]

Answer (score 1):

> Q. Is that even possible?

<strike>No, Izanagi cannot be used/casted on others. It's a *genjutsu* which is cast upon themselves by the users. It is stated in the wiki page of [Izanagi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanagi).</strike>

> Izanagi is a genjutsu that is cast on the user instead of others and
>   is the most powerful amongst this type of genjutsu.

After referring to [Happy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6064/1604)'s answer, the answer is **Yes**, it is *possible*.

---

> Q. I feel as if I saw an Uchiha member use Izanagi to revive a bunch of other Uchiha members.

But then, as for your doubt regarding an Uchiha member saving/reviving many other Uchiha members by using Izanagi, it is *Wrong* and it is also mentioned in the 3rd bullet point of the [`Trivia`](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanagi) section of Izanagi (emphasis mine).

> The anime makes several mistakes on what Izanagi actually does and is
>   capable of. For example when used by Danzō, every hit would cause one
>   of his Sharingan eyes to close when using Izanagi instead of closing
>   when the time limit ended. **And during Itachi's history of Izanagi and
>   Izanami to Sasuke, Izanagi was used beyond the personal reality of the
>   user to bring a whole swath of people back to life even though they
>   weren't using Izanagi themselves.** Similarly, unlike Danzō and Obito's
>   usage, where their used eye is closed after passing their time limit,
>   in the anime-exclusive flashback, the user's eye instead turns blank
>   like the usage of Izanami.

Comment: They make mistakes in the anime !!!! Thanks for letting me know @R.J

Comment: @RikuduSennin - Well there are many more mistakes which have been done in the anime, but then, we always have SE network to get our questions answered!:)

Comment: This is wrong! The Naruto wiki is not canon, and sometimes carries a lot of misinformation. Don't rely on it too much. :)

Comment: @Happy - Thanks for correcting me. I edited the answer accordingly! :) Though the Izanagi being used to revive others, it is wrong and my answer is pretty much acceptable regarding that! :)

Comment: I think the Rikudo Sennin might still be able to use Izanagi to revive others, because ... you know, he is the Sage of Six Paths. :D But a random filler flashback Uchiha being able to do that is simply ridiculous!

Comment: @Happy - Ofcourse he can do that, but I think that technique would be the *Creation of All Things*. It is the parent technique of Izanagi, AFAIK! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it can twist one point in reality to fit your needs. danzo only used it for himself cause he is selfish lol.